# How to get the current system date in a string - ANDROID

Tags: android, date

How can i get the current date in a string in Android?

I know that it's gettable using

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
String formatDate = df.format(c.getTime());
```

But i get it as 25-Mar-2014, and what i want is 25-3-2014. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this..

Change `dd-MMM-yyyy` to `dd-MM-yyyy`

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
String formatDate = df.format(c.getTime());
```

Answer (score 2):

This is surprisingly the only answer which does exactly what the OP wants (okay a very small subtlety):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy");
String formatDate = sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
System.out.println(formatDate);
```

Note, that there is only one pattern symbol M, not two! So the output is not

25-03-2014

but

25-3-2014 (what was explicitly asked for)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
                            .format(new Date());
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are passing for `DateFormat` `dd-MMM-yyyy` will gives you month in words. Change it to  `dd-MM-yyyy`

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
 String date = sdf.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the date format as `SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");` not like `SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");`. Here is the doc for [SimpledateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
String formatDate = df.format(c.getTime());
```

Comment: That would give the month as name. But the Op wants the month as number representation not as the word representation.

Answer (score 1):

Simple change!

Use#

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Instead#

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   String dateInString = "7-Jun-2013";
try {

    Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
    System.out.println(date);
    System.out.println(formatter.format(date));

} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Date date = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try this one...


Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    String formatDate = df.format(c.getTime());

    System.out.print(formatDate);


if you want to change vice versa means follow below  steps..

    int selectedYear = 2013;
    int selectedDay = 20;
    int selectedMonth = 11;

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, selectedYear);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, selectedDay);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, selectedMonth);
    String format = new SimpleDateFormat("E, MMM d, yyyy").format(cal.getTime());


or else

DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.ENGLISH);

or 

GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        int y, m, d, a;

        y = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        m = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
        d = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        cal.set(_year, _month, _day);
 String format = new SimpleDateFormat("E, MMM d, yyyy").format(cal.getTime());

hope it will help you
```